# Why does Sql server write 100's of files to System Volume Information (all with the same name)

Tags: sql-server-2005

I noticed that SQL Server has a surprisingly large number of writes to `\System Volume Information\{guid1}{guid2}`

What is Sql Server doing when something like this happens?

[image]

In the above image half of my write IO for sqlsevr.exe is used for the System Volume Information writes.

This is being run in Windows 7 Profressional.

---

here is the output of `vssadmin list shadows`

```
vssadmin 1.1 - Volume Shadow Copy Service administrative command-line tool
(C) Copyright 2001-2005 Microsoft Corp.

Writer name: 'Task Scheduler Writer'
   Writer Id: {d61d61c8-d73a-4eee-8cdd-f6f9786b7124}
   Writer Instance Id: {1bddd48e-5052-49db-9b07-b96f96727e6b}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'VSS Metadata Store Writer'
   Writer Id: {75dfb225-e2e4-4d39-9ac9-ffaff65ddf06}
   Writer Instance Id: {088e7a7d-09a8-4cc6-a609-ad90e75ddc93}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'Performance Counters Writer'
   Writer Id: {0bada1de-01a9-4625-8278-69e735f39dd2}
   Writer Instance Id: {f0086dda-9efc-47c5-8eb6-a944c3d09381}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'ASR Writer'
   Writer Id: {be000cbe-11fe-4426-9c58-531aa6355fc4}
   Writer Instance Id: {6584bb82-094c-4896-9be2-880ff9fb4d80}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'System Writer'
   Writer Id: {e8132975-6f93-4464-a53e-1050253ae220}
   Writer Instance Id: {669bba38-6066-4bf6-99af-8d312f66648d}
   State: [5] Waiting for completion
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'SqlServerWriter'
   Writer Id: {a65faa63-5ea8-4ebc-9dbd-a0c4db26912a}
   Writer Instance Id: {48de0d7f-b7a0-457e-8bab-fefe2089286e}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'MSSearch Service Writer'
   Writer Id: {cd3f2362-8bef-46c7-9181-d62844cdc0b2}
   Writer Instance Id: {d5c4ab16-b67e-4476-976b-4dba610084d8}
   State: [5] Waiting for completion
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'WMI Writer'
   Writer Id: {a6ad56c2-b509-4e6c-bb19-49d8f43532f0}
   Writer Instance Id: {5e334911-6049-4d29-8d33-d9b230b46ec2}
   State: [5] Waiting for completion
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'COM+ REGDB Writer'
   Writer Id: {542da469-d3e1-473c-9f4f-7847f01fc64f}
   Writer Instance Id: {e9dde2da-5cee-4d65-ac50-45387be4b600}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'Registry Writer'
   Writer Id: {afbab4a2-367d-4d15-a586-71dbb18f8485}
   Writer Instance Id: {9825b95f-94a0-438b-a359-4111aa308a60}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'BITS Writer'
   Writer Id: {4969d978-be47-48b0-b100-f328f07ac1e0}
   Writer Instance Id: {d23d67d3-c421-4e9a-9965-123ec802bfcc}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error
```

[Here is the output](http://pastebin.com/Ur15b29m) of `vssout list shadows` (too long to post here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Windows doing shadow copies of your E-drive.

(This is not normal to use on data/log drives for SQL server, it increases I/O tremendously).

Edit: Or, well.. atleast schedule it to something sane, like one hour before everyone comes to work.

Comment: This also happens with my C drive when I was using a database on C. Where would I go to shut it off/change the scheduelling.

Comment: Right-click on the drive, select properties. There is a "Shadow Copies" tab.

Comment: I am on Windows 7 Professional, I do not have a Shadow Copies tab. The only thing I can think of is the Previous Version tab but I can only turn it on and off, there is no way to schedule it.

Comment: Running SQL server on Windows 7?.. Oh well, there is no way to modify how it works - you can only disable it completely by disabling the shadow copy service. Be aware that you'll lose important snapshots when doing windows update etc.

Comment: @Scott - also,  if you're running SQL server on Windows 7, it would have been a good idea to put that info into your question. From the FAQ, this site is for systems admins working on things that would generally be called production systems - that excludes personal desktop issues, unless it's related to managing lots of desktops.

Comment: @mfinni you are right, this server does only service me, I have flagged for a moderator to move this to SuperUser.

Answer (score 4):

Smells like VSS snapshots.

Do you have software (probably backups) telling SQL Server to create VSS snaps?

Comment: Where would I go to check?

Comment: Check what you've got in `vssadmin list writers` and `vssadmin list shadows`

Comment: (you'll need to run those commands in a command prompt that's been started as administrator)

Comment: I did, now its a matter of decoding what it returning. VSS is something I have never worked with before.

Comment: I updated my original post with the output of the two commands, I do not know what I am looking for so I know what to disable.

Comment: Looks like everything's copying.  Do you have backups configured in the "Backup and Restore" control panel?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1356/discussion-between-scott-chamberlain-and-shane-madden)

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that you're doing a backup of the server itself, or a backup of the SQL Server databases with a VSS aware backup program (Windows Backup, SQL Maintenance Plan or SQL database backup job, or third party VSS aware backup software).

Answer (score 0):

You can also disable shadow copy on the folder of your database's files:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa819132(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.serverfault.com/faq) for more info.